# Help with DC Motor

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, resistors, dc-motor

I have a little yellow dc motor. I checked on google for the spec and it looks like this :

[image: Motor spec]

As I’m using a 5V source, I calculated that with a resistor of 50 ohms, that should do it. When I connected the motor, nothing happened.

I then connected the motor directly to the 5V supply (no resistor) and it started to work. I checked the current with only the motor and it was about 120mA.

I then thought the motor had some kind of internal resistance, so I checked it with my multimeter and measured around only 7 ohms.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just remove the resistor. If you let the motor run, it will "choose" the right current by itself. (But if you stall it, by holding the wheel, it will take a higher current and may eventually burn out. So, don't do that for a long time)

Comment: 5V divided by the 100mA of a running motor equals 50 Ohms.  But 5V divided by a 7 ohms stalled motor when it starts equals 714mA. Then if you put a 50 ohms series resistance the current will be 5V divided by 57 ohms which equals 88mA which is WAY too little current to start it.

Comment: Incidentally these different resistances are why you sometimes see the word impedance.  There is an effect called inductance that resists changes in the flow of current and capacitance that resists changes in voltage.  Motors work based on inductance, which works based on magnetic fields, allowing you to translate electrical energy into rotational torque (and losses).  You can use inductance and frequency to calculate inductive reactance, and you use inductive reactance and resistance to calculate impedance.  Impedance determines current flow rather than resistance.

Comment: @audioguru: thank you! I was still struggling to understand why the motor was not turning with my resistor while I had the 100mA in the circuit. 
I now know that to start, the motor need a lot more current then to « keep turning »

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a lot of basics missing here.

The first and most egregious is thinking that the motor doesn't affect current draw. By doing what you did, you basically assumed that the motor has no control over how much current will flow through it. This is false since it draws more current when it needs to apply more torque. The motor doesn't need a resistor to control the current going through it. It can do that on its own. This first misunderstanding here is the most important one.

Second is understanding what motor specs actually mean. That 100mA is saying that at the motor's design point, it will draw 100mA when you apply 5V *directly* to it. What is the motor's design point? It's the largest amount of load torque that the designer of the motor believed the motor could reasonably provide for long periods of time without overheating or being strained too hard. Since the current draw will vary with the load torque, that means it will probably draw something other than 100mA when you connect your load torque to it.

Third, the motor does have a resistance due to its windings (and hopefully a very low resistance) but there's other stuff inside the motor too. So you cannot treat a spinning motor as just its internal resistance. The only time you can is when the motor is stalled and not spinning. As soon as the motor is spinning it is also acting as a generator and there's an opposing voltage developed inside the motor, in addition to the inductance of the windings, in addition to the internal resistance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was very educative and I really appreciate that you spent time writting it. With audioguru’s comment, I now understand why the motor was not turning with my 50ohms resistor. 
Thanks again